# How to resolve merge conflicts with Azure Devops and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Azure Devops and Visual Studio 2019 (v16.11.2). Had to reset my laptop with a clean windows install and now I seem to be missing something here.

I made several commits in a branch, now I want to merge back into master. On Azure Devops I created a Pull Request, that has two merge conflicts. How do I resolve these?

I can't find a button on Azure Devops web interface and I can't find anything with Pull Request in Visual Studio either where I use the 'Git Changes' pane (instead of Team Explorer). Switching to master and pulling says 'Repository already up to date'

Comment: Was able to merge back to master through 'Git Repository' > right click branch > 'merge into master' then deal with the conflicts. But still seems this should be possible with a proper pull request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On Azure Devops I created a Pull Request, that has two merge conflicts. How do I resolve these?

In Azure DevOps, there is no built-in feature can resolve the merge conflicts.

But we can use the Extension to achieve this feature in Azure DevOps: [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab)

[image]

This is a relatively convenient method.

Comment: Ok this is pretty impressive indeed, thx. Wasn't able to find this through the docs.. They seem to not distinguish very clearly between the old days of Team Explorer and the new Git panes.